# Call server side function from Client Side

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, c#-4.0

I am using Master and Content page.
my client side function is-

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function StateChange(txtState) {
        var state = document.getElementById(txtState);
        PageMethods.StateSelectionChange(state.value, OnSuccess, onFailed);
    }
    function OnSuccess(state, userContext, methodName) {
        alert(state);
    }
    function onFailed(state, userContext, methodName) {
        alert(state);
    }
</script>
```

and server side code is-

```
 public static string StateSelectionChange(string state)
{
    //txtCity.Text = "";
    //if (txtState.Text != "")
    //{
    //    SqlDataReader dr = cm.Allstate(txtState.Text);
    //    if (dr.Read())
    //    {
    //        con.Close();
    //        AutoCompleteExtender2.ContextKey = txtState.Text;
    //        txtCity.Enabled = true;
    //        txtCity.Focus();
    //    }
    //    else
    //    {
    //        con.Close();
    //        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "Alert", "alert('State is not exist');", true);
    //        txtState.Text = "";
    //        txtState.Focus();
    //    }
    //}
    return (state);
}
```

I am not able to access the commented part (textbox and class main function) of that code because of declaring the function as static. If I remove static word from this function then it shouldn't be called from client side.

Finally I want to call non static function from client side using Java script/ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that because all controls are instances and you can access only static members from static methods. One work around that I use is pass control values as parameter to server side method.

Comment: yes sir, that I know but I want to fire ajax request from client side to access code behind non static function, Is it possible ??

Comment: No, for using ajax, method has to be static.